# How to support multiple package versions in CMake's user package registry?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to understand how I can use the [CMake user package registry](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#user-package-registry) to support multiple builds, for example a Debug and a Release build.

I have a package1, which properly calls `export(PACKAGE package1)` so it registers the build directory with CMake's [user package registry](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#user-package-registry). I then proceed to creating 2 separate build directories, one for Debug and one for Release (note that I made the version for the Debug build 3.0.2000000, while the version for the Release build is 3.0.1000000, because I wanted CMake to prefer the Debug build in my use case). As expected, each of these builds registered an item in the registry:

```
> ls ~/.cmake/packages/package1/
212e973d0f1858e4bdf95b9d105bed5a  78094ed9b729d420c3f782cd8e668e64
```

Now in a different project, package2, I use `find_package(package1 3.0.740)` but it only ever finds the one in the Release build. I tried inspecting the `package1_CONSIDERED_CONFIGS` and `package1_CONSIDERED_VERSIONS` right after calling `find_package` but again only the Release build's config and version are there.

The code in package2's CMakeLists.txt file:

```
SET(CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_SORT_ORDER NATURAL)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_SORT_DIRECTION DEC)

message("CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_SORT_ORDER="
        "${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_SORT_ORDER}")
message("CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_SORT_DIRECTION="
        ${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_SORT_DIRECTION}")
find_package(package1 3.0.740)

message("Considered Configs:  ${package1_CONSIDERED_CONFIGS}")
message("Considered Versions: ${package1_CONSIDERED_VERSIONS}")
```

Result of CMake running above code:

```
cmake ../..
-- Using link pool size - 16 jobs
CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_SORT_ORDER=NATURAL
CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_SORT_DIRECTION=DEC
Considered Configs:  /path/to/package1/Release/package1Config.cmake
Considered Versions: 3.0.1000000
```

What am I doing wrong? How is the user registry supposed to be used?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I currently try to simplify a build and I am considering the usage of the CMake user package registry in order to avoid a separate install step. This sounds like a show stopper to me. Do you know if the problem still exists in the latest CMake stable version 3.13.1?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found a way around this issue. After watching Daniel Pfeifer “Effective CMake", it makes you feel like you can really use CMake to handle your package management, but I have found that it's simply not good enough. I'm still using it at the moment, but I'm not very pleased with it. The reason it's still usable for me is that our projects don't yet heavily use the package management, and use it just with pre-packaged release builds. If people start needing a side by side debug build of dependent packages, we're going to need to start using conan.

Comment: I should mention I'm also delaying the need for better package management by simply merging internal projects into a mono-repo, and using cmake's package management just for third party libraries. This means it's less likely someone would need a debug build, and also that I don't really use the CMake user package registry that much. In it's current state I think it's more or less useless. It really needs some TLC by cmake devs to be useful.